# Limit in norm of a Sobolev space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, sobolev-spaces

I consider, for $s>\frac{1}{2}$, the space $L^{2,-s}(\mathbb{R}^3)=\bigg\{f: \int_{\mathbb{R}^3}|f(x)|^2(1+|x|^2)^{-s}<\infty\bigg\}$ and I have to show that the function $$f(x)=\frac{e^{i\sqrt{\lambda+i\varepsilon}|x|}}{|x|}$$ converges in the norm of the considered space to$$g(x)\frac{e^{i\sqrt{\lambda}|x|}}{|x|}$$when $\varepsilon\to 0$ where $\lambda>0$ and from complex analysis $\sqrt{\lambda+i\varepsilon}=\sqrt{\lambda_\varepsilon}+i\frac{\varepsilon}{2\sqrt{\lambda_\varepsilon}}$ with $\lambda_\varepsilon=\frac{\sqrt{\lambda^2+\varepsilon^2}+\lambda}{2}$, so $\lambda_\varepsilon\to\lambda$ and $$e^{i\sqrt{\lambda+i\varepsilon}}=e^{i\sqrt{\lambda_\varepsilon}}e^{-\frac{\varepsilon}{2\sqrt{\lambda_\varepsilon}}}\to e^{i\sqrt{\lambda}}$$.
 Then I consider the integral
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{|e^{i\sqrt{\lambda+i\varepsilon}}-e^{i\sqrt{\lambda}}|^2}{|x|^2}\frac{1}{(1+|x|^2)^s}dx $$
The integrand tend to $0$ when $\varepsilon\to 0$ almost everywhere and it is majorized by $$\frac{1}{|x|^2(1+|x|^2)^s}$$ integrable. So by the theorem of dominated convergence I have the thesis. Is it right?